# Vue.js: Checking if a v-for loop that uses a v-if conditional rendered any items?

Tags: vue.js

If I have the following code:

```
<template v-for="(item, index) in items" v-if="item.name === 'foo'">
   <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
</template>
```

How would I print out a message if this loop outputs nothing?

Thanks!

Comment: use <slot> should be able to meet your requirements.

Comment: i mean, you can do a v-if on another element checking if items is null or if items.length == 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a computed property to create the filtered list. Then you can use a `v-if` based on the list length. For example

```
computed: {
  fooItems () {
    return this.items.filter(({name}) => name === 'foo')
  }
}
```

and in your template

```
<template v-for="(item, index) in fooItems">
  <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
</template>
<p v-if="fooItems.length === 0">
  Nothing to show
</p>
```